# How to calculate the distance of 2 points in a 10x10 grid

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics

I have a 10x10 grid of squares, where each square represents a sequential number from 0 to 99.

```
9 | 19 | 29 | 39 | 49 | 59 | 69 | 79 | 89 | 99 |
8 | 18 | 28 | 38 | 48 | 58 | 68 | 78 | 88 | 98 |
7 | 17 | 27 | 37 | 47 | 57 | 67 | 77 | 87 | 97 |
6 | 16 | 26 | 36 | 46 | 56 | 66 | 76 | 86 | 96 |
5 | 15 | 25 | 35 | 45 | 55 | 65 | 75 | 85 | 95 |
4 | 14 | 24 | 34 | 44 | 54 | 64 | 74 | 84 | 94 |
3 | 13 | 23 | 33 | 43 | 53 | 63 | 73 | 83 | 93 |
2 | 12 | 22 | 32 | 42 | 52 | 62 | 72 | 82 | 92 |
1 | 11 | 21 | 31 | 41 | 51 | 61 | 71 | 81 | 91 |
0 | 10 | 20 | 30 | 40 | 50 | 60 | 70 | 80 | 90 |
```

How to calculate the distance between square to another square.
The distance is calculated by steps like king in chess, it can move only 1 step adjacently / diagonally.

For example:

- the distance between 0 to 63 is 6 (11, 22, 33, 43, 53, 63)
- the distance between 32 and 39 is 7 (33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39)
- the distance between 33 and 33 is 0
- the distance between 18 and 60 is 8 (27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 62, 61, 60)

If possible, it should work on 8x8 grid as well or 3x8 and so on..

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: You didn't say what precisely your 'distace' is. Based on examples given I guess it is a chess king's path length, that is a minimum numer of steps across the square edge or a square corner. Am I right?

Comment: yes, it can move freely like chess king's path.

Comment: I just updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the notation easier, I'm going to use $(r,c)$ to represent a cell where $r$ is the row number and $c$ is the column number.

Consider two cells, $(r_1, c_1)$ and $(r_2, c_2)$. Define their distance as,

$$d((r_1, c_1),(r_2,c_2)) = \max\{|r_2-r_1|,|c_2-c_1|\}.$$

So in the context of the grid with the numbers, you simply need to look at the difference between the one's digits and the difference between the ten's digits and take the larger of the two.

Comment: so how do you calculate the input f(0, 63) = 6?

Comment: If you write $0$ as $00$, then $\max\{|6-0|, |3-0|\} = \max\{6,3\} = 6$.

Comment: wow that's amazing! how did you come up with that.. does it work with 8x8 grid? what if it's a 100 x 100 grid?

Comment: G Sassatelli provides an explanation in his answer. The gist is that you need to at least move the maximum vertical or horizontal distance. To cover the shorter of the two, we can move diagonally during some moves without sacrificing our movement in the longer of the two distances.

Comment: It should work in an 8 by 8 board. It'll work on a 100 by 100 board but you'll need to use a different numbering system such as separating the row and column number with a comma in the grid.

Comment: oh ya! I just tried with 8x8 board and it works! the way I got the x is by doing floor(0 / number of rows) and floor(63 / number of rows) and I got the y by (63 % number of rows) and (0 % number of rows). Do you think it's ok?

Comment: Looks like you got the right idea :)

Answer (score 2):

I get two nodes have distance $1$ if they share either a side or a corner, and the distance between any two squares is the length of the shortest path between them.

It is evident that the shortest path $(a,b)\to (c,d)$ has the same length as the shortest paths $(c,b)\to(a,d)$, or $(a,d)\to(c,b)$: you are just choosing a different diagonal on the rectangle $\langle(a,b);(c,b); (c,d);(a,d)\rangle$.

It is also evident that the shortest path $(a,b)\to(c,d)$ is as long as the shortest path $(c,d)\to(a,b)$.

So, up to the aforementioned symmetries, you can always reduce to the case $(a,b)\to(c,d)$, with $a\le c$ and $b\le d$.

Every time you move to the right, you have the option of getting a free move up by moving through the corner instead of the side; viceversa, every time you move up you can move left for free. So, the length of the path $(a,b)\to (c,d)$ is at most $\max\{\lvert b-a\rvert,\lvert c-d\rvert\}$.

On the other hand, you need *at least* to move as much in one of the co-ordinate directions to get from $(a,b)$ to $(c,d)$.